# White backgrounds on iPhone showing inset, very light, yet visible pink rectangular area

Tags: iphone, screen

Working on an iPhone app I noticed a very light, yet quite noticeable pink-ish rectangular area that's inset from the screen's edges uniformly by about 4 millimeters (0.16 inches) in all views with a white (light?) background. After spending a lot of time trying to figure out which of my app's view layers might cause this, I discovered that other apps such as WhatsApp, Messenger etc. show the same phenomenon on any white background. Not surprising then, a screenshot captured just shows a plain white background.

I wonder what this is? A normal effect of the background lighting? A weird setting I have overlooked? A defect?

I'm fine with the effect, as I don't seem to be causing it in my app, but still curious what it is that has caused me to waste quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue on a lot of iPhone 5/5s models. Supposedly, Apple has replaced the screens for free in the past, but the phone is old enough now they probably don't offer replacements any more.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5324198?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to resolve this for me! My Google search didn't bring up anything useful (and I felt a bit stupid for searching for "iphone pink screen..." ;-). If it's not me that's causing this, I'm fine for now. Apple has treated me decently enough in the past to let this slip...